# I have the following code it says cannot resolve symbol mMap().what should i do?

Tags: google-maps, android-studio

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
if (mMap == null) {
```

Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment:

```
mMap=((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], most likely you have `mMap` in a different scope, but you omitted all information on scope when you pasted your excerpt, so it's impossible to help you out without your actual code.

Comment: i have taken this code from github but it is based on an older version of google play services whereas i want to use an updated version.and I am unable to make changes to it,kindly help https://github.com/IndoorAtlas/android-sdk-examples/blob/master/Basic/src/main/java/com/indooratlas/android/sdk/examples/wayfinding/WayfindingOverlayActivity.java#L260

Answer (score 0):

you most likely would have to define it as a field, so that this filed can be access then:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
```

... and the comments there states `might be null if Google Play services APK is not available`, which means, you might be running this on an emulator (or a device), which lacks these play services. in this case, you'd just have to create an `AVD` from an image with play services. if you want to reference later versions, you have to edit the [build.gradle](https://github.com/IndoorAtlas/android-sdk-examples/blob/master/Basic/build.gradle).

Comment: i have tried many solutions but then when i run the activity the google map won't appear

Comment: @amnasherafal updated my answer, while it is not easy to tell what is wrong, while having no clue what you've changed and/or on which device it is running (as explained above).

Comment: i have just updated the build gradle, google play services to 11.8.0 as I am using firebase which requires the updated google play services verision. I am not able to understand your solution?

Comment: talking about this: https://medium.com/@dai_shi/installing-google-play-services-on-an-android-studio-emulator-fffceb2c28a1 while there are images which have play services installed, in Android Studio AVD manager. what you've updated there is only the client for the services on the device.

Comment: I am new to android studio and I cannot understand this. I am running my android application on my device what does it have to do with this.It only gives me the error cannot resolve symbol getMap()